# How to communicate between Laravel and Android?

Tags: php, android, database, laravel, rest

I want to understand the communication between a web application written in Laravel and an Android one. I would like to know how should I structure the folders since they will have different functionalities for the web platform and for the mobile. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate across different platform you can use `JSON` to pass the data and read that data.

In `Laravel` just create the `API` which returns `JSON` data and access that `API` in `Android` using `AsyncTask`, `Volley`, `HttpUrlConnection`, `OkHttp`.

Just search on the internet you will find lots of resources.

Check [this link](http://www.expertphp.in/article/create-restful-api-using-laravel-5-with-resourceful-routes-example) to create `API` in `Laravel`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `WEB API` to achieve this.

What is an API?

> In this sense an API - which stands for Application Programming
>   Interface - allows for publicly exposed methods of an application to
>   be accessed and manipulated outside of the program itself. A common
>   usage of an API is when you wish to obtain data from an application
>   without having to actually visit the application itself. To allow this
>   action to take place, the application has published an API that
>   specifically allows for foreign applications to make calls to its data
>   and return said data to the user from inside of the external
>   application.

[How to create WEB API help](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, write the Web API using the Lavarel to enhance communication between the android app and the web application. Ensure you test the json file using Postman to check if it returns valid json parameters. Then use either Retrofit, Volley in Android to communicate with the android application to parse JSON objects to enable access to information at real time...